# How can I buit a plug-in for Email Application Built-in Android?

Tags: android

I want to built a plug-in to filter Email by mail Address and sent it to Spam 
How can I buit a plug-in for Email Application Built-in Android?  and APIs??

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, sorry. There are no public APIs for the Email (or Gmail) applications. You might consider contributing to the K9 open source Android email client.

Comment: @Antonio: You can't prove a negative. It is up to *you* to prove there *are* documented and supported public APIs for those apps. I wouldn't waste your time.